# Trying to add CSS to Docbook using Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, docbook

I am trying to add a CSS file to my Docbook HTML output.  Most examples say:

```
xsltproc --stringparam html.stylesheet  corpstyle.css  chunk.xsl  myfile.xml
```

Ours is a Saxon based toolkit... So accordingly, I changed the build file to:

```
<java jar="${DocBook}/saxon/saxon.jar" fork="true" dir="${gen.dir}/html-multi">
         <arg line="com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet"/>
         <arg line="${basedir}/book.xml "/>
         <arg line="${DocBook}/html/chunk.xsl "/>
         <arg line="html.stylesheet=mycss.css"/>
      </java>
```

When running ant, this results in:

Bad param=value on the command line.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems more like an Ant problem, try

```
<java jar="${DocBook}/saxon/saxon.jar" fork="true" dir="${gen.dir}/html-multi">
         <arg line="${basedir}/book.xml "/>
         <arg line="${DocBook}/html/chunk.xsl "/>
         <arg line="html.stylesheet=mycss.css"/>
      </java>
```

as it seems the main class is taken from the `jar` argument.

Comment: Generally I would recommend (a) running XSLT from Ant using the xslt task rather than the java task, and (b) using Saxon 9.5 rather than Saxon 6.5 even when your stylesheet is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet.